# Maven throwing error during "mvn site" but works fine with "mvn compile"/"mvn test"

Tags: java, maven, arraylist

Today i was trying to generate the report using the site command through Maven and encountered a problem during the compilation phase.

### ERROR:

```
ParseException in /Users/rajesh/Documents/workspace/mobileads/mobileads-core/src/main/java/com/nimbuzz/mobileads/util/AdRequestAnalyticsLogger.java
Last useful checkpoint: "com.nimbuzz.mobileads.util.AdRequestAnalyticsLogger.logAdOk(AdRequest,String)"
Encountered " ">" "> "" at line 32, column 55.
Was expecting one of:
    "boolean" ...
    "byte" ...
    "char" ...
    "double" ...
    "float" ...
    "int" ...
    "long" ...
    "short" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "?" ...
    "boolean" ...
    "char" ...
    "byte" ...
    "short" ...
    "int" ...
    "long" ...
    "float" ...
    "double" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "?" ...
    "?" ...
    "?" ...
    "?" ...
```

To my surprise when i run the compile or test command the same files compile properly.

Now I have two doubts here

1). When i go to AdRequestAnalyticsLogger.java where it is giving me this problem i could see the code as

```
final List<String> toBeLogged = new ArrayList<>(ad.asList());
```

mind it there is not String in tilts after ArrayList.

Now the doubt is,Does java accept the "ArrayList<>" rather then "ArrayList".If it is suppose to be "ArrayList" then how come it is compiling but not working when doing "mvn site".

2). What are the difference between "mvn compile"/"mvn test"/"mvn site"

Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: Are you compiling to java 7? Since you have diamonds in your code. mvn site executes the following goals after compile: test package verify install. So the problem likely lies in one of those goals. `mvn clean install` should give you the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You have a plugin in your site lifecycle that doesn't know how to parse the Java 7 diamond operator you're using.

Take a look at the log before that error to see which plugin it is. You'll either need to configure it to expect Java 7 or upgrade.

Possibly related to [JAVANCSS-9](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JAVANCSS-49):

> I get the following parse error, when using the cobertura-maven-plugin (2.5.1) with the javancss-maven-plugin (2.0):
>   ...
>   The code piece uses Java 1.7

now fixed in the latest version.